# How to validate form field in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I want to make shure that the current value of the `bid field` is not less than current biggest `bid`. This is my form with a custom `clean` method.

Form:

```
class Place_A_Bid_Form(forms.Form):
    listing = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"type":"hidden"}))
    bid = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}), min_value=1)

    def clean_bid(self, biggestBid):
        bid = self.cleaned_data["bid"]
        if bid < biggestBid:
            raise ValidationError("""New bid shouldn't be less than starting bid, or 
                                    if any bids have been placed then new bid 
                                    should be greater than current biggest bid""")
        return bid
```

View:

```
def place_a_bid(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Place_A_Bid_Form(request.POST)
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        biggest_bid = Bid.objects.filter(user=user).aggregate(Max("amount"))
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            user_obj = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
            listing_obj = Listing.objects.get(title=data["listing"])
            Bid.objects.update_or_create(
                user=user_obj,
                listing=listing_obj,
                amount=data["bid"]
            )
        return redirect(listing_obj)
```

In view I am extracting current value that I am going to compare to, and I can't figure out how to pass this value to my form field's `clean` method. Or maybe I'm doing this wrong? So how to do properly this sort of validation?

Comment: Did you solve problem?

Comment: @eisa nahardani Nope. I'm gettting error: TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'biggest_bid'

Comment: Oh,  aggregate output was problem in the case, i updated my answer

Comment: @eisa nahardani I spot the issue with the dict. Now it works. But how to give a user a ValidationError feedback if his bid is not exceed current highest bid?

Comment: do you mean that user can receive the error in your template? is this a new question?

Comment: This is sounds like a new question, but I initially considered providing feedback to the user as part of the validation process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Place_A_Bid_Form(forms.Form):
    listing = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"type":"hidden"}))
    bid = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),
    min_value=1)

    def __init__(self,biggestBid=0 *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.biggestBid = biggestBid

    def clean_bid(self):
        bid = self.cleaned_data["bid"]
        if bid < self.biggestBid:
            raise ValidationError("""New bid shouldn't be less than starting bid, or 
                                    if any bids have been placed then new bid 
                                    should be greater than current biggest bid""")
        return bid
```

and then in views.py:

```
def place_a_bid(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        dict = Bid.objects.filter(user=user).aggregate(Max("amount"))
        form = Place_A_Bid_Form(biggestBid=dict['amount__max'], data=request.POST)
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            user_obj = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
            listing_obj = Listing.objects.get(title=data["listing"])
            Bid.objects.update_or_create(
                user=user_obj,
                listing=listing_obj,
                amount=data["bid"]
            )
        return redirect(listing_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django's [**`IntegerField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) can validate a minimum value without any extra logic, you can set the `.min_value` and add a validator with:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

class Place_A_Bid_Form(forms.Form):
    listing = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'hidden'}))
    bid = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs, min_bid=0):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        bid = self.fields['bid']
        min_bid += 1
        bid.min_value = min_bid
        bid.validators.add(MinValidator(min_bid))
```

so then you only need to pass the `min_bid` to the form:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def place_a_bid(request):
    biggest_bid = Bid.objects.filter(user=request.user).aggregate(
        min_bid=Max('amount')
    )['min_bid'] or 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Place_A_Bid_Form(request.POST, min_bid=biggest_bid)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            listing_obj = Listing.objects.get(title=data['listing'])
            Bid.objects.update_or_create(
                user=request.user,
                listing=listing_obj,
                amount=data['bid']
            )
            return redirect(listing_obj)
    else:
        form = Place_A_Bid_Form(min_bid=biggest_bid)
    return render(request, 'app_name/name-of-template.html', {'form': form})
```

This also construct a form in case of a GET request with the biggest bidding as minimum bid. This will also add this as `min="biggest-bid"` in the HTML so the browser can validate this. This can thus also validate the bid already at client side before submitting the form, but will also properly validate the form at the server side.

It might however be better to pass the listing not through the form, but as a URL parameter.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).